# Floating a div left pusheds text content of another div

Tags: css, html, css-float, css-position

Floating left on one div element causes another with position:absolute to reposition text outside its div container when overflow is set to visible (not when set to hidden).
I recreated the situation here: http://jsfiddle.net/Thohar/9M2CX/
CSS:

```
#left {
    width: 150px;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #77BDC9;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px; /* to get beneath the */
}

#tha_fly {
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible; /* IMPORTANT - only when set to hidden will the text content stay inside div*/
    top: 200px;
    left: 500px;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want the text to stay in the div tag.  I don't understand the principle behind why it moves.

Comment: Change #tha_fly to position:absolute.

Comment: Can you please tell me the name of that class you have applied to that div ? actually I am not getting which div you are talking about..

Comment: @fred02138 Thank you that seems right. Can you tell me why position relative would put the text in one place and the surrounding div in another?

Comment: @MinderSaini If you click the link to jsfiddle, it should be clear. There is no class involved.

Comment: But there are 9 divs in the fiddle. If only 2 are important, why are the other 7 there?